# content.toggleAnimationClass(); is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smoothstate.js

I have the **html** and **css** working fine with the most basic use of *smoothState.js*

```
;(function ($) {
 $('#main').smoothState();
})(jQuery);
```

However even with this basic implementation if you select the link of the current page, *(i.e. to reload the page)* you will get a blank *white* screen with *2015* written in the top left corner. with this error there is ***No error recorded in console*** which makes me think it's an error handled by **smoothState.js**

If I expand on smoothState to allow for the more advanced options, *(i.e. 'is-exiting')* it now becomes impossible to navigate through the site, move off the page.

With the advanced implementation, shown at the end of this question I get the console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: content.toggleAnimationClass is not a function main.js:134
    $.smoothState.onStart.render @ main.js:134
    load                         @ jquery.smoothState.js:533
    clickAnchor                  @ jquery.smoothState.js:589
    n.event.dispatch             @ jquery.min.js:3
    n.event.add.r.handle         @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Here's the **html**:

```
<head></head>
<body>
 <div id="main" class="m-scene">

  <header id="header">
  </header>

  <div id="page_content_container" class="scene_element scene_element--moveUpIn">

   <section class="about-intro-container">
   </section>

   <section class="about-services-container">
   </section>

   <section class="about-randomBits-container">
   </section>

   <footer>
   </footer>

  </div><!-- #page_content_container -->
 </div><!-- #main -->

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.smoothState.js"></script>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the smoothState relevant **css**:

```
/* prefixes are just missing here, I have them in my file */

.m-scene .scene_element {
  animation-duration: .5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.m-scene .scene_element--moveUpIn {
  animation-name: moveUp, fadeIn;
}

.m-scene.is-exiting .scene_element {
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
}

@keyframes moveUp {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%) 
  }
  100% { 
    transform: translateY(0%) 
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

And here's the more advanced smoothState:

```
;(function($) {
  'use strict';
  var $body = $('html, body'),
  content = $('#main').smoothState({

    // Runs when a link has been activated
    onStart: {
      duration: 250, // Duration of our animation
      render: function (url, $container) {

        // toggleAnimationClass() is a public method
        // for restarting css animations with a class
        content.toggleAnimationClass('is-exiting');

        // Scroll user to the top
        $body.animate({
          scrollTop: 0
        });
      }
    }
  }).data('smoothState');
  //.data('smoothState') makes public methods available
})(jQuery);
```

Eventually I plane to add **prefetch**, **pageCacheSize** etc... and implement different transition depending on what page your are loading/exiting. However at this time it doesn't seen worth moving forward until I can resolve the above issues.

Any ideas or assistance is welcome and very much appreciated, **Thanks.**

**Oh I just got this error also**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/Parallelos/Developer/paralellos.github.io/projects.html.
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
  n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery.min.js:4
  n.extend.ajax                             @ jquery.min.js:4
  fetch                                     @ jquery.smoothState.js:355
  load                                      @ jquery.smoothState.js:529
  clickAnchor                               @ jquery.smoothState.js:589
  n.event.dispatch                          @ jquery.min.js:3
  n.event.add.r.handle                      @ jquery.min.js:3
```

Comment: where is `toggleAnimationClass` definition.. I think it is not done as a plugin function

Comment: @ArunPJohny I just assumed it was defined in `jquery.smoothState.js` given `toggle()` is jQuery method and `toggleAnimationClass()` is used in the documentation, [Add page transitions to your site](http://miguel-perez.github.io/smoothState.js/typical-implementation.html). Have you used it? How have you or others implemented `toggleAnimationClass()`?

Answer (score 12):

I dealt with this exact same issue. If you download the demo's and go through their 'functions.js' you'll notice a different way of handling the exiting css class. Here is that code, have tested it and it works for me.

```
$(function(){
  'use strict';
  var $page = $('#main'),
      options = {
        debug: true,
        prefetch: true,
        cacheLength: 2,
        forms: 'form',
        onStart: {
          duration: 250, // Duration of our animation
          render: function ($container) {
            // Add your CSS animation reversing class
            $container.addClass('is-exiting');
            // Restart your animation
            smoothState.restartCSSAnimations();
          }
        },
        onReady: {
          duration: 0,
          render: function ($container, $newContent) {
            // Remove your CSS animation reversing class
            $container.removeClass('is-exiting');
            // Inject the new content
            $container.html($newContent);
          }
        }
      },
      smoothState = $page.smoothState(options).data('smoothState');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that method is removed, not to restart animation try

```
content.restartCSSAnimations()
```

Comment: That seems to have improved the situation some. with `restartCSSAnimations()` I can now move around the site. However I believe the idea behind `toggleAnimationClass()` was to dynamically add the `.is-exiting` animation so the page transition would run on the current page exiting. Under this `restartCSSAnimations()` use the current page just vanishes, then the new page transitions in. Also If I click the current page link I still get that blank white page with _2015_ written in top left corner.

Comment: @Paralellos I haven't used the plugin before.. but just went through the code and found this method.. but in the current code base I'm not able to find the `toggleAnimationClass` method... may be support for the same is removed?

Comment: Yeah I see it. That's strange. So do you think they just haven't updated the examples to show this new method?

Comment: @Paralellos looks like that... the code used in the example has the method.... http://miguel-perez.github.io/smoothState.js/javascripts/all.js .. if you want you can try to extract the plugin code from the attached js file